# Live system vs guest (virtual machine) system

Tags: linux, security, virtual-machine, liveusb

Suppose I had a custom *ix image file, and I wanted to use it for testing something, be it a program, a website or something else which I need to be in an isolated environment. If I make sure I was always running as an unprivileged user in the live system, will it be as secure as the guest system in a virtual machine? I don't need persistence.

As an extension, is there a way to restrain a live system from being able to chroot into the computer's drive?

Answer (score 0):

Things go bad during tests (this is what tests are meant for :)), so if you miss out something, on a "bare metal" system you'll have to reinstall. With a VM you just restart using a fresh image. Choose wisely :)

Comment: Main reason why I prefer a live system is that my computer cannot handle a virtual machine well (there's an issue with my RAM chip). I don't have access to other computers at the moment either.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment, so: @shards have you tried creating a bootable USB to use? You can make it so that root has no password to login so the existing filesystems can't be mounted without root privileges. An added bonus is that the USB will be loaded into RAM so there won't be leftover files.

For distributions based on *Gnu/Linux*:

[Chroots are not meant to be a security feature](https://github.com/earthquake/chw00t) and shouldn't be used as such. To answer your question:

To create a more [secure chroot environment](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Security_Handbook/Chrooting_and_Virtual_Servers), create a directory with bash or your prefered shell, its linked libraries, and the other tools you require. Directly from the just referenced wiki page:

```
# mkdir /chroot

# ldd /bin/bash
  libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x4001b000)
  libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x40060000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x40063000)
  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x40000000)
```

Create the directories needed for the shared libraries linked to bash + any other executables you will be using:

```
# mkdir /chroot/bash
# mkdir /chroot/bash/bin
# mkdir /chroot/bash/lib
```

And copy those libraries to the correct directories.

Unfortunately I misread the question twice and have yet another unrelated answer to containers instead of chroots below.

The latest kernel documentation describes how to defend against [Spectre](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/spectre.html), one of the major issues with a guest system/unprivileged container escaping from a virtual machine. You can the current status of your processor in regards to such vulnerabilities with:

`tail -n1  /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/* | sed 's/\/.*\///g'`

And comparing the results with the expected results described in the documentation.

Make sure `CONFIG_RETPOLINE` is enabled in the kernel, which it should be by default. Other protective options are `CONFIG_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG` and `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`. There are other options as well that you may enable that distributions will leave off due to performance tradeoffs.

An essential step is to have the latest microcode firmware either built into your kernel, loaded by your BIOS, or loaded by your initramfs that will update your processor microcode upon every boot. Your distribution will likely the latest for you, assuming you keep your system updated. For reference, AMD mot[AMD's latest microcode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amd-ucode) is located at the official kernel git tree, and [Intel's latest microcode](https://github.com/intel/Intel-Linux-Processor-Microcode-Data-Files) is hosted on Github. The config to allow loading microcode into the initramfs/cpio is under `CONFIG_MICROCODE`, while you may choose to build it in with the kernel by directing `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` to the correct directory.

You may also opt to recompile GCC with [Intel's patch](https://github.com/clearlinux-pkgs/gcc/blob/master/zero-regs-gcc8.patch) that will allow you to use the `-mzero-caller-saved-regs` argument when compiling your kernel.

<strike>You would need to have a version of Windows that supports `Process Isolation` for your containers.</strike>

In order of relevance:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/faq

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/process-isolation

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/containers-vs-vm

It is also needed to keep Windows updated with security patches relevant to Spectre/Meltdown, which may allow escapes from a virtual machine or container.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073757/protect-windows-devices-from-speculative-execution-side-channel-attack

Comment: The question is about Linux....